# Confused about the lambda expression in python

Tags: python, lambda

I understand the normal lambda expression, such as

```
g = lambda x: x**2
```

However, for some complex ones, I am a little confused about them. For example:

```
for split in ['train', 'test']:
    sets = (lambda split=split: newspaper(split, newspaper_devkit_path))

def get_imdb():
    return sets()
```

Where `newspaper` is a function. I was wondering what actually the `sets` is and why the `get_imdb` function can return the value `sets()`

Thanks for your help!

Added:
The codes are actually from here [factory.py](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/lib/datasets/factory.py)

Comment: Are you sure that code is correct? It's really odd to keep reassigning `sets` every iteration.

Comment: I think this is just OP's attempt at creating a minimal example. This code is not his own according to the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sets` is being assigned a lambda that is not really supposed to accept inputs, which you see from the way it is invoked. Lambdas in general behave like normal functions, and can therefore be assigned to variables like `g` or `sets`. The definition of `sets` is surrounded by an extra set of parentheses for no apparent reason. You can ignore those outer parens.

Lambdas can have all the same types of positional, keyword and default arguments a normal function can. The lambda `sets` has a default parameter named `split`. This is a common idiom to ensure that `sets` in each iteration of the loop gets the value of `split` corresponding to that iteration rather than just the one from the last iteration in all cases.

Without a default parameter, `split` would be evaluated within the lambda based on the namespace at the time it was called. Once the loop completes, `split` in the outer function's namespace will just be the last value it had for the loop.

Default parameters are evaluated immediately when a function object is created. This means that the value of the default parameter `split` will be wherever it is in the iteration of the loop that creates it.

Your example is a bit misleading because it discards all the actual values of `sets` besides the last one, making the default parameter to the lambda meaningless. Here is an example illustrating what happens if you keep all the lambdas. First with the default parameter:

```
sets = []
for split in ['train', 'test']:
    sets.append(lambda split=split: split)
print([fn() for fn in sets])
```

I have truncated the lambdas to just return their input parameter for purposes of illustration. This example will print `['train', 'test']`, as expected.

If you do the same thing without the default parameter, the output will be `['test', 'test']` instead:

```
sets = []
for split in ['train', 'test']:
    sets.append(lambda: split)
print([fn() for fn in sets])
```

This is because `'test'` is the value of `split` when all the lambdas get evaluated.

Comment: When we call the `fn`, could there be no parameters? Take the example of `g = lambda x: x**2`, we need to call it as `g(2)`, and `g()` doesn't make sense. If it has default parameters, then it seems okay since the values have already be generated when creating it. But for the ones without default parameters, should we use `print([fn(split) for fn in sets])` for the last example?

Comment: In the last example the lambda function is defined as `lambda: split`, i. e. it is something as `def func():` (a function without parameters). If lambda function uses parameter(s), it have to be defined e. g. as `lambda x: x ** 2` (your first , understandable example) - with parameter name(s) between `lambda` and `:`.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function:

```
func = lambda x: x**2
```

can be rewritten almost equivalently:

```
def func(x):
    return x**2
```

Using either way, you can call the function in this manner:

```
func(4)
```

---

In your example,

```
sets = lambda split=split: newspaper(split, newspaper_devkit_path)
```

can be rewritten:

```
def sets(split=split):
    return newspaper(split, newspaper_devkit_path)
```

and so can be called:

```
sets()
```

---

When you write the following:

```
def get_imdb():
    return sets()
```

you are defining a "closure". A reference to the function `sets` is saved within `get_imdb` so that it can be called later wherever `get_imdb` is called.

Comment: You do not address the purpose of the default parameter or the fact that all values of `sets` but the last are discarded. `def get_imb(): ...` does *not* create a closure. It just makes a normal function call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confused about the `split=split` part. This has the same meaning as it would have in a regular function: the split on the left is a parameter of the lambda function and the split on the right is the default value the left split takes when no value is provided. In this case, the default value would be the variable `split` defined in the for loop.

So, answering your first question (what is `sets`?):

`sets` is a variable to which an anonymous function (or lambda function) is assigned. This allows the lambda function to be referenced and used via the variable `sets`.

To your second question (why can `sets()` be returned?), I respond:

Since `sets` is a variable that acts as a function, adding parenthesis after it calls the lambda function. Because no parameters are given, the parameter `split` takes the value `'test'`, which is the last value the for loop variable `split` takes. It is worth noting here that, since `sets` is not defined inside the function `get_imdb`, the interpreter looks for a definition of `sets` outside the scope of `get_imdb` (and finds the one that refers to the lambda function).